# Get max sum of fields group by another field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

My MongoDB is storing payments received using this class:

```java
@Document
public class Payment {
  @Id
  private Integer id;
  private String sender;
  private String recipient;
  private Double amount;
  private Date date;
}
```

I want to find the five recipients who received more money in a range of time.

How can I achieve this using Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter by date between two values and order them by amount field in descending way to get the first 5. This can be acommplished with this JPA method:

```
List<Payment> findFirst5ByDateBetweenOrderByAmountDesc(Date startDate, Date endDate)
```

Comment: This will give me only the 5 biggest payments, I need to retrieve the recipients with the highest revenue between the given dates. So I need to sum the amounts and group the results by the recipient.

Comment: Using @Query annotation is always a solution for more complex queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Query` to fetch the results, it filters the payments that are between startDate and endDate and group by recipients to order the recipients based on the sum of amount of payments that they were involved in:

```
@Query("SELECT p.recipient FROM Payment p WHERE p.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY p.recipient ORDER BY SUM(p.amount) DESC LIMIT 5");
private List<String> getResults(
    @Param("startDate") Date startDate,
    @Param("end") Date endDate
);
```